# How to scale watermark in percent with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, scale, watermark

I run a video site, but watermark logo still in different sizes in every video with different resolution. 
My question: is there a way to scale watermark image in every video by some kind of percentage?
I use next command:

> /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i video_in.mp4 -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -r 30 -movflags
>   faststart -profile:v baseline -vf "movie=logo.png, scale=200:37
>   [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=10:10 [out]" -s 640x360 -acodec
>   libfaac -ab 128k -ar 44100 video_out.mp4

So as you see the scale of watermark is static, but I want to make it dynamic. Is there way to do this in percentage by depending of video resolution?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Get the dimensions of the video:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries stream=width,height -of \ 
default=noprint_wrappers=1 video_in.mp4
```

This will print the width and height.

```
width=1280
height=720
```

Scale the watermark:

```
ffmpeg -i watermark.png -y -v quiet -vf scale=1280*0.15:-1 scaled.png
```

The `-1` calculates the height based on the aspect ratio of the original image.

Apply scaled watermark to video:

```
ffmpeg -i video_in.mp4 -i scaled.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" video_out.mp4
```